# why is an empty char field in Django read out as None and not an empty string?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model for example like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    text = model.CharField(max_length=50)
    extra_text = model.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

Lets say I have an object instance where `extra_text` is blank, so in the database it is stored as an empty string `''`

I read that object, for example:

```
myitem = Item.objects.get(id=1)
```

Now I check what is the value of `myitem.extra_text` and it is not `''`, but `None` (here in IPython shell):

```
In [36]: myitem.extra_text == ''
Out[36]: False

In [37]: myitem.extra_text == None
Out[37]: True

In [38]: myitem.extra_text is None
Out[38]: True
```

Shouldn't it be `''` at this point? It is `''` in the database, as it is not allowed to be `NULL`.

My problem is that such object can not be saved unmodified back to the database, because if I try I get:

```
In [39]: myitem.save()
<skipping Traceback>
IntegrityError: null value in column "extra_text" violates not-null constraint
```

I find it very strange that an object instance I just read from the database and not modified in any way, can not be saved back to the database. Am I doing something very wrong? What is the proper way to solve this problem?

Comment: can you get into PostgreSQL (`manage.py dbshell`) and tell us what's really being stored in your db in the `extra_text` field of your model? I can't think of something else

Comment: @julio.alegria yes I did that, and in the database the `extra_text` field has `''` everwhere: `SELECT count(*) FROM myapp_item WHERE extra_text = ''` gives 40, but `SELECT count(*) FROM myapp_item WHERE extra_text IS NULL` gives 0

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of one scenario where this would occur:

You have an existing model with existing entries in the database. You then add a new CharField but neglect to provide a default for existing items to use. When you query an existing item, that CharField will not have a value, but will also not be allowed to be NULL, and you get the integrity error.

If that sounds familiar, you should be able to fix it by simply specifying a default value (even if it's just `''`) when adding the field.

Comment: Well, this extra_text was a new field, but I do have a default `''` for that field, and I've checked with psql that all entries have a value of `''` in the database, but in Django they are read out as None and Django tries to save them bank as NULL. So this should not occur?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: I was using [django-modeltranslation](https://code.google.com/p/django-modeltranslation/) on this model, on this field, and I thought it only has influence on the template, and I thought that outside templates item.extra_text would still relate to the extra_text column in the database. But it appears that even in the shell it also uses the localized (into the default language) extra_text_en column, and that one was NULL.

I have now updated `extra_text` field in all rows to `''` in the database, and made it `NOT NULL DEFAULT ''`, so now when I read it into Python, its `u''`. But the thing is that 
django-modeltranslation still wants to save it as NULL in the database, which results in `IntegrityError: null value in column "title_extra_en" violates not-null constraint`.

So I still don't know how to make it work with `django-modeltranslation`.